# What are colored morphisms/arrows intended to mean in these diagrams?

Tags: category-theory, universal-property, morphism, natural-transformations, diagram-chasing

I've been reading more category theory as a prerequisite to understanding some more complicated theorems, and for the first time I'm running into arrows that are distinctly colored. Examples include these diagrams from Wikipedia for natural transformations and universal morphisms:

[image: The Wikipedia Diagram for Natural Transformations]

[image: universal Morphism]

The Wikipedia articles do not ***readily*** show me a link to where the coloring for these diagrams is explained, and I have not seen these colored diagrams in the textbook I have been reading for Category theory. Why are these arrows (and objects) colored blue and red? Better yet, (if possible) can someone give me a link/source/textbook that explains this coloring procedure? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Like anything, for emphasis.  There isn't any "math" here.

Comment: Then I could recolor those arrows black and lose nothing? I know for instance that dashed arrows are used to indicate unique arrows, so I suspected this coloring might mean something else. Does that mean that I can recolor these arrows black in my own personal diagram and lose no "information" about the diagram, unlike how I would if I turned a dashed arrow solid in some diagrams?

Comment: Dashed usually indicates existence, not necessarily uniqueness.  Again, the color doesn't matter.  Look at a textbook in categories:  it will be black and white.

Comment: The colours have highlighted the natural transformations and the universal arrow, so you can see which is which and don't forget what the diagram is saying. I have studied a fair amount of category theory and I can truthfully say I can only remember seeing coloured arrows in *your* questions. It is not a common thing